# How to pull mongodb logs with Wazuh agent?

Tags: mongodb, elk

I did following settings on `/var/ossec/etc/ossec.conf` and after that I restart agent but it's not showing logs on the Kibana dashboard

```
<localfile>
<log_format>syslog</log_format>
<location>/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log</location>
```

Answer (score 1):

I performed a basic installation of Wazuh + MongoDB on agent side with the following results:

- MongoDB by default writes inside syslog file located at `/var/log/syslog`.
- Inside `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` there are internal mongo daemon logs that are more specific.

We could monitor such logs on Wazuh agent by:

```
  <localfile>
    <log_format>syslog</log_format>
    <location>/var/log/syslog</location>
  </localfile>
```

This rule is included by default on the agent but anyway is good to remember.
the other one as you point it out:

```
  <localfile>
    <log_format>syslog</log_format>
    <location>/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log</location>
  </localfile>
```

I only see that you didn't copy the closing tag `</location>` but it could be copy mistake, whatever is good to take a look at `/var/ossec/logs/ossec.log` to find some error.

With that configuration we could receive alerts like this:

```
** Alert 1595929148.661787: - syslog,access_control,authentication_failed,pci_dss_10.2.4,pci_dss_10.2.5,gpg13_7.8,gdpr_IV_35.7.d,gdpr_IV_32.2,hipaa_164.312.b,nist_800_53_AU.14,nist_800_53_AC.7,tsc_CC6.1,tsc_CC6.8,tsc_CC7.2,tsc_CC7.3,
2020 Jul 28 09:39:08 (ubuntu-bionic) any->/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
Rule: 2501 (level 5) -> 'syslog: User authentication failure.'
2020-07-28T09:39:07.431+0000 I  ACCESS   [conn38] SASL SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for root on admin from client 127.0.0.1:52244 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user "root" for db "admin"
```

If we run `mongo -u root` (with bad password) on agent side.